# Purpose of %s while we don't reference any string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have the following working code in python

```
webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe 
%s").open("http://google.com")
```

But it doesn't work without `"%s"`. What is the purpose of `"%s"` here?

Comment: Did you RTM? https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html

Comment: have you ever started a program, from the command line, with arguments?

Comment: No I am getting this error *** Error("could not locate runnable browser")*** while running it in my program

Comment: @Stuart this looks like an undocumented usage, as `get` expects a browser name not a path, OP is passing a path with a placeholder for the url

Answer (score 0):

`%s` is a placeholder for a string. It uses the same syntax as `"".format()`, to provide the URL to the browser program. This isn't a documented usage of `webbrowser.get`, and it seems to be doing approximately `os.system("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe 
%s".format("http://google.com"))`

I would suggest `webbrowser.get('chrome').open("http://google.com")` is simpler and more portable, or the even more portable `webbrowser.open("http://google.com")`, if you want to respect your user's choice of preferred browser.

Comment: As     `webbrowser.get('chrome').open("http://google.com")`                  is erroring. I went for                                   
 `webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe 
%s").open("http://google.com")`                                                    Anyway I got the Reason Why "%s" is used here. Thank you :).

Comment: It looks like `chrome` is not found on your system. You can try adding "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/" to your path

Comment: No `chrome` is actually present in my system but the code works only with `%s`

Comment: I didn't say "chrome is not installed". I said "chrome is not *found*", because it isn't in any of the places that `webbrowser` looks.